# Invalid Scopes: manage_pages - Instant Articles

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I am using this app for instant articles. For three hours, I am getting the below error; what do I need to do? When I asked if instant articles apps also need to do app review, the FB support team told no need to review. But now I am getting this error:

> Invalid Scopes: manage_pages, pages_manage_instant_articles,
>   publish_pages. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your
>   app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the
>   documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Also I am using login product: I am not using the login to collect details from users. I only use this to login from my component, to give access from my site to instant articles.

[image]

Comment: There is no "your support team" here - your readers are not Facebook technical support. I have amended the question to make this clear.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure.. Got what u said.. Will follow

Answer (score 3):

This is the reason why you are getting that error:

> Public Mode — Apps in public mode no longer allow their admins, developers, or testers to access permissions or features that normally
>   require app review. This affects all apps built after May 1st, 2018,
>   immediately. Apps built before then will not be affected until August
>   1st, 2018.

More information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0, under the section titled "90-Day Breaking Changes".